# Do all themes accommodate all features?

Tags: themes

Do different themes accommodate different features, or can all themes accommodate any feature?

I.e. do I need to bear in mind what features I'll need when I choose a theme, or are themes only how things are laid out visually?

Also, is it possible to change the image in the default theme 'Twenty Eleven'?

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all Themes accommodate all features; but to answer that question more precisely, you'll need to be more specific about what you consider to be "features".

Things that are generally considered *Theme* features are fairly well-represented by [the list of filter tags for WORG repository-hosted Themes](http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/tag-filter/). You'll notice that these things generally deal with *presentation* of content.

Things dealing with *creation* or *management* of content are generally considered *Plugin* territory, and generally speaking, any Theme *should* accommodate such Plugins.

(Your second question is unrelated, and should be asked in a separate question.)